# How to delete entries/relationships in SugarCRM Web Service

Tags: sugarcrm

SugarCRM Web Service API provide only methods for **Set** and **Get** entries/relationships.

How can I do **delete/remove** entries and their relationships with entries in other related modules?

Is the  Web Service API designed only for Get and Set?

Comment: Good question. I don't see anything like that in the REST API. Deliberate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the 'deleted' flag to '1' as one of the fields in the 'name_value_list' in the set_entry/set_entries call and it will mark a record deleted.

http://gist.github.com/4019840

For relationships, you can use set_relationship/set_relationships and pass the argument '1' for the 7th argument to that call will delete the relationships instead of add them.

http://gist.github.com/4019851